# Error in declaring a variable inside the component class and outside the render function to use it inside the render function in react

Tags: reactjs, class, variables, render

in the code bellow when I declare the varable characters via destructuring

```
const { characters } = this.state;
```

I get a  Unexpected token error.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    characters: [
      {
        name: "Charlie",
        job: "Janitor"
      },
      {
        name: "Mac",
        job: "Bouncer"
      },
      {
        name: "Dee",
        job: "Aspring actress"
      },
      {
        name: "Dennis",
        job: "Bartender"
      }
    ]
  };
  removeCharacter = index => {
    const { characters } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      characters: characters.filter((character, i) => {
        return i !== index;
      })
    });
  };
   const { characters } = this.state;
  render() {
   
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <Table
            characterData={characters}
            removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter}
          />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is a sandbox of the code:[sandbox with the error, look at the app.js file](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mkxxmp46p)

and when I put the declaration inside the render function there is no problem,
look at the [correct](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0mk07j45q) code sandbox.

Also when I create a variable, outside of the render function (of the App.js file), without const or let for example:

```
x=1;
```

It works fine when I use it inside the render function as this.x, but when I declare it with let,const or var it throws me an Unexpected token error.

How do you explain that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You have destructed characters outside the render method.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "./Table";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    characters: [
      {
        name: "Charlie",
        job: "Janitor"
      },
      {
        name: "Mac",
        job: "Bouncer"
      },
      {
        name: "Dee",
        job: "Aspring actress"
      },
      {
        name: "Dennis",
        job: "Bartender"
      }
    ]
  };
  removeCharacter = index => {
    const { characters } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      characters: characters.filter((character, i) => {
        return i !== index;
      })
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { characters } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <Table
            characterData={characters}
            removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter}
          />
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: why this is not leggal?

Comment: you can't use destruction `{ }` at class level.

Comment: ah ok thank you! 
but why I can't declare a variable with const,let or var but when I declare the variable only by using the name of the variable, for example x = 1; is valid?
the above declarations are on class level